# layoutSubviews freezes the app when added to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I would like to be notified when my custom UICollectionView gets its size. It is created from xib.
I've added the following function:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: segmentWidth(), height: segmentHeight())
    self.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
}
```

This function is called endlessly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please correct your code, you have 2 function declarations, probably a typo

Comment: @CZ54 Thanks. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to update the layout like this when the collection view changes.

In fact, because you're using a Flow Layout there should be a much easier way of getting it to do what you want.

I presume that `segmentHeight` and `segmentWidth` are functions that depend on the size of the collection view which is why you need to recalculate them?

If so then you should be able to use the `delegate` functions of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

First update your view controller with a new protocol...

```
class MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

This will then let your view controller act as a delegate for the flow layout.

And use the method...

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: segmentWidth(), height: segmentHeight())
}
```

That **should** be it.

If I've missed anything out let me know but you should get everything you want from that.

After that just delete the `layoutSubviews` method and it should be performing as you want.

Comment: @Luda will edit question. Sorry, just left a quick answer from my phone :D